# How do I indent multiple lines at once in Notepad++?

Tags: ide, editor, text-editor, notepad++, tabs

In many text editors that are aimed at programmers, if the user has a selection that spans more than 1 line and presses the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, those lines are indented by 1 <kbd>TAB</kbd> (or a number of spaces, depending on how the editor is configured).

However, this does not seem to be the default behavior of Notepad++. Is there a way I can do this in Notepad++, or is there a plugin that I can get to allow me to do this?

Edit: Upon additional testing, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> correctly un-indents the lines as expected, but only a tab simply inserts a tab wherever the carat is. This is in version 5.4.5 Unicode

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was with the QuickText plugin. After removing it, indent worked as normal.

Answer (score 13):

Capslock + Tab to indent multiple lines at once. Highlight the text first.

Answer (score 12):

The problem with the new version of QuickText seems to be that it is set to react to the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.  Previously it was set to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  If you change the key combination in the shortcut mapper then your <kbd>TAB</kbd> key should start working again, and QuickText should also work (with whatever new key you've assigned).

Answer (score 8):

It works fine for my v. 5.4.5 of Notepad++.  I just select multiple lines and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

If you want <kbd>TAB</kbd> to be replaced by <kbd>SPACE</kbd> than you need to go Settings > Preferences and select Edit Components tab.  Next check Replace by spaces check box in Tab Setting section.

**Update**: In a newer version of Notepad++ this option is in Settings > Preferences > Language section.

Comment: it appears to be not applicable to version 7.8.1, can not find 'replace by spaces'.

Comment: @old-monk You right. It looks that 'Replace by space' checkbox is in the Language section now.

Comment: Precisely `Settings->Preferences...->Language` .. look for checkbox

Answer (score 5):

If you're using QuickText and like pressing Tab for it, you can otherwise change the indentation key.

Go Settings > Shortcup Mapper > Scintilla Command. Look at the number 10.

- I changed 10 to : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> and
- 11 to : <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>LEFT</kbd>.

Now I think it's even better than the <kbd>TABL</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> as default.

Comment: Thanks for the details of how to actually _find_ the block indent. That allowed me to actually get what I wanted done. Also, I really like your mappings, I also think it's better than <kbd>TAB</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

I have Notepad++ 5.3.1 (UNICODE). I haven't done any magic and it works fine for me as described by you.

Maybe it depends on the (programming/markup/...) "Language"?

Comment: 5.1.1 (Unicode) here and works too. Independent of the selected syntax highlighting language.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the [NppAutoIndent](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) plug-in, select **Plugins > NppAutoIndent > Ignore Language** and then **Plugins > NppAutoIndent > Smart Indent**.

Comment: Hi Anshi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that writing in ALL CAPS is difficult to read and looks like shouting.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ will only auto-insert subsequent indents if you manually indent the first line in a block; otherwise you can re-indent your code after the fact using TextFX > TextFX Edit > Reindent C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

in Notepad++v6.1.8 (Unicode) it works after removing the QuickText plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To increase indent - Press and hold `TAB`

---

To decrease indent - Press and hold `TAB` + `SHIFT`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions here is good but new answers to old questions that already have good answers should give new insights and new information. Just repeating information already in other answers is not useful.